# issue with mutex locks on android API 22

Tags: java, android, c++, multithreading, android-ndk

I have a producer/consumer model of code that looks as follows:

```
std::queue<int> globalQueue;
std::mutex addmutex;

void ConsumerThread() {
    while(true) {
        bool isEmpty = false;
        {
            std::lock_guard<decltype(addmutex)> lock(addmutex);
            //std::cout << "Checking is empty" << std::endl
            isEmpty = globalQueue.empty();
        }
        .... //Further code to process
    }
}

void Producer(int value) {
    std::lock_guard<decltype(addmutex)> lock(addmutex);
    //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10000));
    globalQueue.push(value);
}
```

So the weird thing I'm noticing and this is only on API 22 (API 23 and above work fine) is that when the producer takes control of the lock the consumer thread is not blocked when checking for empty. I verified this by adding a print statement inside the consumer thread as show in commented code and by delaying the producer thread post lock as shown by commented code there too. The result of this is that even when something gets added to the queue the consumer always thinks it is empty.

I'd expect the print out of "Checking is empty" to stop for 10 seconds when calling producer, which it does on API 23 and above but not on API 22.

The consumer thread is started from java code using a new java Thread which calls the C++ ConsumerThread method on this new thread at startup to start consumer.

I'm using the latest version of NDK 13.1.3.